# Laravel - HTTP Client return 403

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a project with **Laravel** to manage the endpoint calls and **Vue** to control frontend.

When user do a login the response (a **token**) saved in the *localStorage*,then in *app.js* i add this token automatically to all calls.

**Login**

```
  axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.token != null) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
            //PUSH SECOND PAGE
          }
        })
```

**App.js**

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Token " + token
}
```

Now, we´ll see the problem.

When we go to the second page a endpoint call will be launch automatically to fill some inputs. This call theoretically have a localStorage token.

```
 mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/elements")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**Routes** (API endpoints)

```
Route::get('elements', 'HeaderController@elements')->name('header.elements');
```

**HeaderController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class HeaderController extends Controller
{
    public function elements()
    {
        $response = Http::get('API');
        return $response->json();
    }
}
```

This returns **Access Denied**. The token is informed in the header.

Is curious but if we call directly to the API through Axios response will be correct, but if we use a Laravel endpoint return this Access Denied.

So: Anybody see the error? Why axios returns right response but Laravel return 403?

**UPDATE 1**

LoginController Laravel Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
   // use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

   /* public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }*/

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $response = Http::post('API', [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);
        return $response->body();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2** (**Ignore this i fix it**)

When i call API trough **Axios** has

> Content-Type: application/json

if i use **Laravel** endpoint has

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

**UPDATE 3**

Array i expected in Endpoint response

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "body": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "entity": "Test1",
            "agrupations": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "A"
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "entity": "Test2",
            "agrupations": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "C"
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "D"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "entity": "Test3",
            "agrupations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "E"
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "F"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "entity": "Test4",
            "agrupations": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "G"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE 4**

I comments auth route to avoid routes conflicts

**Web.php**

```
//Auth::routes();
```

[image]

**UPDATE 5**

Full cURL.

Mmmm, maybe Laravel X-XSRF-TOKEN and SRF-TOKEN 'broke' something.

This doesn´t work (Using Laravel for Endpoint)

> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/elements' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
>   -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6IjV4aU9qOXpaY2FoLytIQ1RTSi9jZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWTlmOUcwL21Ld0xVYXZwdWZyVDJhVktzczlJSzVtdHE2UUsvREp3Nm51RjBZYStaaXptYmx0N0F0bzVkWTQvQiIsIm1hYyI6IjE3OWFiOGU5ZjFjZDhhMDc4OTUzYmJjZDUxZWYwMWY3MzgyOTg3YjM0MjFlNjk5MTc0MGExZDNmYmQ2YzIzY2IifQ=='
>   -H 'Authorization: Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODUxNTYzMjgsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmFyc29uLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhbGFyYSIsImV4cCI6MTU4NjAyMDMyOH0.Mv968xR4IAdbkgqABvg2CLNxSc6mkFPxqEKm9VbbFYOg-H5Ppo80DEsoj8F8pT2yoY7LHF5P_zMbWymAwxPzvQ'
>   -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest:
>   empty' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site:
>   same-origin' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H 'Referer:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/lora/' -H 'Accept-Language:
>   es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'Cookie:
>   XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjV4aU9qOXpaY2FoLytIQ1RTSi9jZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWTlmOUcwL21Ld0xVYXZwdWZyVDJhVktzczlJSzVtdHE2UUsvREp3Nm51RjBZYStaaXptYmx0N0F0bzVkWTQvQiIsIm1hYyI6IjE3OWFiOGU5ZjFjZDhhMDc4OTUzYmJjZDUxZWYwMWY3MzgyOTg3YjM0MjFlNjk5MTc0MGExZDNmYmQ2YzIzY2IifQ%3D%3D;
>   lorawan_session=eyJpdiI6IjZEa1ZQWkY1ZHhYamxPaUxSWGFvdUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaGltclROWnZPTWR4TWZZa3VzcUU4ekZjUklUUWlSNGo5U1pPM1ZLcVpJU0NoVS9ma1hmTS9reW1ENWNWMHJNcSIsIm1hYyI6ImUyYWVkZmUxYTk2M2IzMWQ5MTkyY2RkYzZjZDA3N2U5YTdjNDhiYzliNGQzZjEzOGYzMjFiODJhZWFlMjE3ODcifQ%3D%3D'
>   --compressed

This work (Using Axios to call directly API)

> curl "API" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: application/json,
>   text/plain, */*" -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" -H "X-Requested-With:
>   XMLHttpRequest" -H "Authorization: Token
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODUxNTcyODksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmFyc29uLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhbGFyYSIsImV4cCI6MTU4NjAyMTI4OX0.9MfXYgBDhYltmbfz7rwFWhL0dQUFFRO43ioK8cVlM2C1_-9GolXeC9e55hEclmP4bTuGWfS5HOj9SOWXiDowLA"
>   -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149
>   Safari/537.36" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000" -H
>   "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site" -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" -H "Referer:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/lora/" -H "Accept-Language:
>   es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" --compressed

Comment: The issue will be at your authorization layer. How are you authenticating users? Are you meant to send the header as 'Token abc...' or 'Bearer abc...'?

Comment: Does your internal `Http::post('API', [...])` request require authentication? You might need to forward the `Authorization`-header there as well.

Comment: Why would it be necessary to add the token in Laravel? I'm already adding it globally in App.js, I try too get App.js const token and  pass to the endpoint but i don´t know how can i get it.

Comment: I update question.

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre your LoginController seems to Proxy-Forward your request to another api call, that's the reason. Anyway according to you updated question: Can you add `Accept: application/json` header to you axios request? This will tell laravel that you are only accepting json responses. Otherwise laravel might return an text/html if you'll encounter an error inside laravel.

Comment: I update the question again with better and more details. Anyway i tried what you say and and returns same error .

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre could additionally add the curl from your browser? Open your browser's dev tools, Open the Network Tab, "Right click" on the broken request which serves html, `Copy -> Copy as cURL` and add it to your question? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Added cURL from network.I don´t see any strange. I test the web in Laravel server (php artisan serve) but i don´t think this causes error.

Answer (score 0):

Update your axios header to a Bearer token.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests